# Convert character into date

Tags: date, strptime

I try to convert the character "Friday, March 24, 2017 4:39:46 PM" into a date, but it does not work. `dat.1` results in NA. Can anyone tell me, how to fix it.

```
dat <- c("Friday, March 24, 2017 4:39:46 PM")
dat.1 <- strptime(dat, format="%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
dat.1
```

Result

```
[1] NA
```

EDIT. K..pradeeep pointed out that the code is running on his pc. On my it does not work. I use a Macbook Air, OS X 10.12.3. Version:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness
```

Comment: It is working for me, It is returning `[1] "2017-03-24 16:39:46 IST"`

Comment: Thanks. And if you do `class(dat.1)`, what is the result?

Comment: `> class(d)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" `

Comment: I don´t need to load a package to use `strptime`, isn´t it?

Comment: no you don't have to, it is comes with basic R setup. Not sure why you are having a problem.

Comment: Thank you for testing it:-)